# Win8 WinJS (Javascript) Drag and Drop in ListView

Tags: listview, windows-8, winjs

How do I implement drag and drop for a WinJS ListView control. I can't seem to find any examples. Basically I have a To Do List which I would like to be able to drag and drop elements to sort the priority. Thanks for any help!

## Update

This is now supported in WinJS 2.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#DragAndDropListView

Comment: This [post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605121547/http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Drag-and-Drop-in-WinJSUIListView-for-repositioning-items-in-Windows-Store-Apps.aspx) has a full explanation on how this can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported in WinJS 2.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg182879.aspx#DragAndDropListView